# Why my migration has problem at "enable-migration" level?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-migration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dw6X.jpg)

I writed String Length but this error seid my fild is not string at migration time and zi maked a new project but this error is showing now too!

Comment: Your migration for current project is already Enabled.

Comment: No never. And I can not continue too